# Javascript Regular Expression for a specific numeric pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm actually looking for a javascript regex for a numeric pattern. Regex should accept any numeric input of below formats but not **0.0.0**

**Condition:**

- each segment in the pattern ranges between 0-10

**Valid**
2.9.6
0.6.10
10.10.10
0.0.1

**Invalid**
0.0.0

Any help would be appreciated..!! Thank you...!!

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: Capture the groups and compare using `if` statement. Using everything in a complex regex might slow down your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!0\.0\.0$)(?:\d|10)\.(?:\d|10)\.(?:\d|10)$/
```

Comment: it will fail for `00.1.1`

Comment: @Rajesh: What's the problem, this not allowed.

Comment: @Rajesh: Yes, but what's wrong with my regex, it does the job.

Comment: Please check https://www.regex101.com/r/UoLyBl/1. All 3 inputs are valid but you regex is allowing only 1

Comment: @Rajesh: Re-read the question `each segment in the pattern ranges between 0-10`

Comment: My bad. Also nice catch in my answer. Didn't see that coming. Also in shared link, 1st input should have been valid as `00` is in range `0-10`

Comment: @Rajesh:No problem.

Comment: @Toto: That was perfect for my requirement. Awesome.....! Thank you...!!

Comment: @Rajesh for `00.0.1` would be invalid. Instead i'll take it as `0.0.1`